# How to move all photos from iPhone to iPad?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud, photos

I would like to move all photos from iPhone 5s to iPad Pro 10.5. I want to move them, not copy or sync. Photos in result should be stored on iPad and deleted from iPhone.
I've read this article - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313 -

1. iCloud Photo Library - looks like it will use my iCloud storage. I don't want to upload my photos there and the storage there is relatively small.
2. Manual approach with iTunes - it will require to have a copy of all photos on my Macbook (which I don't want to do - I hate how Apple store/structure photos).

Is there any other way to achieve what I want? 
Surely, it should be exactly the same file as shoot on iPhone - the same file size, the same exif data (no recompression!).

Answer (score -1):

use xender to send photos and if you not have xender open recovery and backup user data  and on ipad open recovery and select the backup in restore user data

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review